# Data flow in React app w/ functional components & hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state, react-functional-component

I'm trying to wrap my head around the data flow in a React app w/ functional components & hooks.

I'm wondering:

1. When a data change (state change) causes a cascade of code to execute... what code (say, in each component, does and does not run... apparently there is selectivity such is "don't put that variable in the deps array if you don't want *that* code to run")?
2. How is the "family" part of the family tree determined during such a data-cascade? Does data pass to siblings? Does it only go to a child (or a parent if a function was passed down for updating the parent)?

To clarify what I have in mind, I have ended each file name with a labeling convention like so: I claim that (and request corrections!) 1 is the parent of 2; 2 is the parent of 3a (I think... can a custom hook be a "child"?), 3b, and 3c; and 3c is the parent of 4c.

Clearly parent/child data flow is a natural part of React. What about sibling to sibling? Is that where problems happen? Certainly "passing data" within a given file can be dangerous (vis-à-vis having control over if and when rendering of a piece of data happens) and apparently the solution is to "lift" the data up the tree. But even still... there is no sense in lifting data up a level (or more) if it isn't clear how it trickles back down... and what problems we should be looking our for.

`index1.tsx`

```
...
<App/>
...
```

`App2.tsx`

```
...
const App = () => {
  ...
  const {varFromCustomHook} = useAppLogic(varToCustomHook);
  ...
  <FooComponent varToFoo={varToFoo} functToFoo={functToFoo}/>;
  <BarComponent/>;
  ...
};
...
```

`useAppLogic3a.tsx`

```
...
interface Props {
  varToCustomHook;
};
const useAppLogic (props: Props) {
...
  return {varFromCustomHook};
};
```

`FooComponent3b.tsx`

```
...
interface Props {
  varToFoo;
  functToFoo;
}
const FooComponent = (props: Props) => {
  ...
  funcToFoo(importantData);
  ...
  <div>{varToFoo}</div>;
  ...
};
```

`BarComponent3c.tsx`

```
...
const BarComponent = () => {
  ...
  <FoobarComponent/>;
  ...
};
```

`FoobarComponent4c.tsx`

```
...
const FoobarComponent = () => {
  ...
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A react component is a react component, whether it is a class-based component or a functional component is an implementation detail. Data flows ***down*** the react tree, parent to child, in the form of props. This is a universal truth in React.

> When a data change (state change) causes a cascade of code to
> execute... what code (say, in each component, does and does not run...
> apparently there is selectivity such is "don't put that variable in
> the deps array if you don't want that code to run")?

When state and/or props update, the functional component is rerendered. The *entire* function body of a functional component is *technically* the "render" function, so *all* of it is run when the component renders.

You ask specifically about hooks. Hooks are also executed each render cycle, in the order they are declared, and if there exists a dependency array, it is evaluated and if *any* dependency fails shallow reference equality check then the hook's callback is triggered.

> How is the "family" part of the family tree determined during such a
> data-cascade? Does data pass to siblings? Does it only go to a child
> (or a parent if a function was passed down for updating the parent)?

The React tree is determined the same way it has almost always been determined, a root node, and children, where each child component can have further children. Data is still passed only from Parent to Child. Callbacks are still passed as props (generally) for a child component to invoke.

#### Comment Questions

> Is useAppLogic considered a child [of App in this case], or can custom
> hooks not be considered children (for whatever reason)? Assuming the
> answer is yes, then couldn't useAppLogic return a value that gets
> passed to its sibling, FooComponent? If yes, wouldn't this be data
> flowing "horizontally" and not down? I don't know the answer... but it
> seems like this kind of data-pass is possible (maybe it is an
> anti-pattern, I don't know).

No, `useAppLogic` is a react hook and can't be a child of anything, it's a function. Only react components, HTML elements, and primitives (string, number, etc.) can be a child, rendered as JSX. Data flows only down. If data needs to be passed to siblings it needs to be lifted to at least the nearest common ancestor. If `useAppLogic` is in `App`, and `FooComponent` is a child of App, then any value returned by the hook can be passed as a prop to `FooComponent`.

> What if (in the above case we have been discussing in these comments)
> useAppLogic was use by both App and App's child, FooComponent? Would
> this be an anti-pattern? This would apparently allow a parent and a
> child to have a piece of data that was not "passed down". (To go out
> on a limb... is this a window into a conversation on global
> data/useReducer?). Maybe these points here in the comments would help
> some people if they were in the answer.

React hooks are each their own instance. They don't share any state, or anything else for that matter. There isn't enough context to say whether or not both parent and child component using the same react hook is an anti-pattern, but I'm inclined to say no, it isn't, since any functional component can use any react hook for just about any reason. Not a window into any global data (*`useContext` hook would be about as close as you could get to some "global" data*).

Comment: Great, thanks! May I ask a couple of questions about something that still bugs me? Is useAppLogic considered a child [of App in this case], or can custom hooks not be considered children (for whatever reason)? Assuming the answer is yes, then couldn't useAppLogic return a value that gets passed to its sibling, FooComponent? If yes, wouldn't this be data flowing "horizontally" and not down? I don't know the answer... but it seems like this kind of data-pass is possible (maybe it is an anti-pattern, I don't know).

Comment: @tarstevs No, `useAppLogic` is a react hook and can't be a child of anything, it's a function. Only react components, HTML elements, and primitives (string, number, etc.) can be a child, *rendered as JSX*. Data flows only down. If data needs to be passed to siblings it needs to be lifted to *at least* the nearest common ancestor. If `useAppLogic` is in `App`, and `FooComponent` is a child of `App`, then any value returned by the hook can be passed as a prop to `FooComponent`.

Comment: Okay cool. I can only think of one more thing and then we will have covered all the bases (related to data flow) that at least I can think of: What if (in the above case we have been discussing in these comments) useAppLogic was use by both App and App's child, FooComponent? Would this be an anti-pattern? This would apparently allow a parent and a child to have a piece of data that was not "passed down". (To go out on a limb... is this point a window into a conversation on global variables?). Maybe these points here in the comments would help some people if they were in the answer.

Comment: @tarstevs Sure. Moved further answers to questions in comments to root answer.